# having trouble while creating a simple jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

here is the link of my jsfiddle

[a simple jquery plugin](https://jsfiddle.net/28jof5th/4/)

in the fiddle on line 147 when i try to do`console.log(this)` then it gives the window object not the element which is passed in the function call on line 166 `$('#loadImage').loadImage()` with the id `loadImage`. It leads to bind a click event handler on the whole window but not on the element. It means event fires when where ever i click on the page. so my problem is why i am not able to access the element but window object at line 147. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bind a handler to a DOM event, the handler is invoked in the `window` context. It's the way DOM event handling works. If you want to access the object that was clicked just look at the event object, look for the `target` property within it. That is the DOM element that was clicked. So, in this case your click handler would look like this:

```
$(this).on('click',function(event){                    
   $('#image_modal').css('display','block');
   // event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();

   console.log($(event.target));

   //$('#image_modal').css('height','100vh');
   //return false;  
});
```

And your console log should point to the element that was clicked.

#### Update

The reason `this` inside the plugin constructor (line 141) is the `window` object is because you're using an arrow function in line 130 to define the plugin. Instead use a declarative function definition:

```
       // Adding function                       // Removed => 
$.fn.loadImage = function (options = null, callback = null) { 
 
    if (options !== null) {
      // loadImage.settings = $.extend(loadImage.settings, options);
      loadImage.updateSettings(options);
    }

    loadImage.init();

       ||  // this points to element calling loadImage
       ||
       \/
    $(this).on('click', function(event) {
      $('#image_modal').css('display', 'block');
      // event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log(this);
      //$('#image_modal').css('height','100vh');
      //return false;   
    });

    $('#modal_close').on('click', function(event) {
      $('#image_modal').css('display', 'none');
      //$('#image_modal').css('height','0px');
      return false;
    });
  };
```

Comment: ya that's cool but how do i add that click handler only to the element. it fires whenever i click any where on page ?